# Get lock details from convictionVoting (even after deleting votes)

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, kusama, governance, referenda

How can we see the lock duration for Referenda (convictionVoting) if the votes are deleted?

On Polkadot and Kusama, if you delete your Referenda Votes it's not possible to see the details of the conviction.

The classLocks are not deleted:

```js
  const classLocks = await apiAt.query.convictionVoting.classLocksFor(account)
  console.debug('classLocks', classLocks.toJSON().sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]))
```

produces:

```bash
classLocks [
  [ 0, 100000000000000 ],
  [ 1, 100000000000000 ],
  [ 10, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 11, 100000000000000 ],
  [ 12, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 13, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 14, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 15, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 20, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 21, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 30, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 31, 20000000000000 ],
  [ 32, 100000000000000 ],
  [ 33, 100000000000000 ],
  [ 34, 100000000000000 ]
]
```

...but I can't see when these locks will release?

If the votes exist on-chain, we can calculate the estimated time remaining:

```js
   const trackIds = [
     0, // Root
     1, // Whitelisted Caller
    //  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
     10, // Staking Admin
     11, // Treasurer
     12, // Lease Admin
     13, // Fellowship Admin
     14, // General Admin
     15, // AuctionAdmin
    //  16, 17, 18, 19, 
     20, // Referendum Canceller
     21, // Referendum Killer
     22, 
    //  21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
     30, // Small Tipper
     31, // Big Tipper
     32, // Small Spender
     33, // Medium Spender
     34, // Big Spender
     35,
     // 36
   ]
   const txs = []

  // for each trackId
  for (let i = 0; i < trackIds.length; i++) {
    const trackId = trackIds[i]
    if (trackId === undefined) continue
    const result = await apiAt.query.convictionVoting.votingFor(account, trackId) //, async (result) => {
    const trackVote = result.toJSON()
    // console.debug('votingFor', trackId, trackVote)
    console.debug('votingFor', trackId)
    // votingFor 0 {
    //   delegating: {
    //     balance: 20000000000000,
    //     target: 'F5212cNTxkoLQV9k3v74hLvdu76GebcxXDEhUR7gR9xMaDn',
    //     conviction: 'Locked6x',
    //     delegations: { votes: 0, capital: 0 },
    //     prior: [ 19889885, 20000000000000 ]
    //   }
    // }
    // votingFor 1 {
    //   casting: {
    //     votes: [],
    //     delegations: { votes: 240000000000000, capital: 40000000000000 },
    //     prior: [ 0, 0 ]
    //   }
    // }
    // 'prior' seems to hold the block number and the amount locked
    if(trackVote.delegating?.prior || trackVote.casting?.prior) {
      try {
        const [blockNumber, amount] = trackVote.delegating?.prior || trackVote.casting.prior
        if (blockNumber === 0) {
          console.debug('no prior block', trackVote.delegating?.prior, trackVote.casting?.prior)
          continue
        }
        const conviction = trackVote.delegating?.conviction || trackVote.casting?.conviction
        console.debug('blockNumber', blockNumber, 'amount', amount/denom, 'conviction', conviction)
        // get the block hash
        const blockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(blockNumber)
        const block = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockHash)
        // console.debug('block', block.block.extrinsics.toJSON())
        // console.debug(block.block.extrinsics.length, 'extrinsics')
        const blockTime = block.block.extrinsics[0].method.args[0].toNumber()
        // console.debug('blockTime', blockTime, moment(blockTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
        const lockTime = moment(blockTime)
        const days = convictions[CHAIN_ID][conviction]
        // console.debug('lockTime', lockTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), 'days', days)
        var unlockTime = moment(blockTime); unlockTime.add(days, 'days')
        console.debug('lockTime', lockTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), 'days', days, 'unlockTime', unlockTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'))
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('error', e)
        process.exit()
      }
    }
  }
```

produces:

```bash
blockNumber 19895325 amount 20 conviction Locked6x
lockTime 2023-09-29 18:42:36 days 224 unlockTime 2024-05-10 18:42:36
votingFor 20
blockNumber 20079887 amount 20 conviction Locked6x
lockTime 2023-10-12 14:55:24 days 224 unlockTime 2024-05-23 14:55:24
votingFor 21
no prior block [ 0, 0 ] undefined
```